# Xcode 11.4 Error - Failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11.4

Not able to install provisioning profiles from xcode.

Ensured that all options for new versions(XCode 11 or later) are added from developer portal and downloading profile.

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Open Devices and Simulators and unpair all paired devices, thats it.

Comment: For those who have this problem but the solutions indicated do not work: it was enough for me to change the CFBundleVersion...
I don't know why xcode was giving me an error related to provisioning profile...

Answer (score 31):

Make sure any connected iPhones/devices are unlocked then trying installing again.

Comment: Simple and stupid solution. Thank you so much. Scratched my had around this.

Answer (score 27):

This looks to be an issue on the XCode side.
The below solution Succeeds!

1. Click on Import Profile[image: import]
2. Then Select the profile you want from the finder window[image: select]
3. Import Succeed!

[image]

Comment: Can you tell the procedure clearly.Where that import option will come

Comment: This worked for me, but the answer needs to be written more clearly. In Xcode, select your target. Select Signing & Capabilities tab. Click the arrows next to your current Provisioning Profile, then select Import Profile.

Answer (score 7):

Select Xcode => Preferences => Accounts => Sign in with your app specific developer account => and select Download Manual Profiles

Answer (score 6):

**Follow the below steps**

1. open Devices and Simulators
2. Remove the paired devices
3. try installing the provisoining profile again

Comment: xcode14 work  perfect.

Answer (score 6):

Manual import via Xcode worked for me under `Signing & Capabilities`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it works this way
Remove any connected devices and try again

Comment: Worked for me.  Unbelievable!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try this:

- open Devices and Simulators
- right click on your iPhone
- choose "Show Provisioning Profiles"
- click the plus icon at the bottom and add your profile

After that the profile should install and your app should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything (restarting iPhone, switching to 5G and back to Wi-Fi, etc. etc.) - nothing worked. Until I randomly tried to disable "Stolen device protection", which I have enabled some time ago. And then everything has just worked. I hope it will help someone with the same issue.